# Programs deployed to Solana do not last forever right?

Tags: solana-program, account

I am learning about the account model in solana and got to the part about Rent. From what I understand if the lamport falls below a particular level, the accounts get purged.

This means programs deployed on Solana in theory do not exist forever...compared with, as far as I can tell, in ethereum where smart contracts deployed are there forever.

Will I be right about this? Or I am getting some concepts confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. if your account does not hold some SOL that can provide the rent needed then that account will get deleted in the next rent cycle BUT there is also something known as rent-exemption in which if you deposit a SOL amount equal to 2 year's worth of rent, then your account will be rent-exempted and will last forever. Of course when you do decide to close that account then the all the SOL deposited in that account will be returned or credited back to you. Hope this helps in your understanding of the concept of rent in solana.